# The getter key was called on null

Tags: flutter, null, key, navigator

Until two days ago the app was running normally. When I tried to run it again yesterday, without making any changes I get the following error:

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
The getter 'key' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: key

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/jakel/Documents/GitHub/app_inspecciones/lib/main.dart:19:5

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      ExtendedNavigator.builder.<anonymous closure> (package:auto_route/src/extended_navigator.dart:37:36)
#2      _MaterialAppState._materialBuilder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/app.dart:756:39)
#3      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7555:48)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:28)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4474:5)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4469:5)
...     Normal element mounting (258 frames)
#266    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
#267    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3306:18)
#268    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1182:16)
#269    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1153:5)
#270    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1095:18)
#271    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2647:19)
#272    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1094:13)
#273    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:934:7)
#274    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:915:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The error is in main.dart

```
Future main() async {
 Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await configureDependencies();
 final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
 await FlutterDownloader.initialize();
 runApp(
   MaterialApp(
     builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(
       observers: [ClearFocusOnPop()],
       navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
       router: AutoRouter(),
       builder: (context, extendedNav) => GestureDetector(
         onTap: () async {
           // esto quita el foco (y esconde el teclado) al hacer tap
           // en cualquier lugar no-interactivo de la pantalla https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/
           final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
           if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
               currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
             currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
           }
         },
         child: Theme(
           data: customTheme, 
           child: BlocProvider(
             create: (context) =>
                 getIt<AuthBloc>()..add(const AuthEvent.startingApp()),
             child: AuthListener(
               navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
               child: extendedNav,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ), //InspeccionScreen(),
   ),
 );
}
```

This is my dependences in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_route: ^0.6.9
  collection: ^1.14.13
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  dartz: ^0.9.2
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  dropdown_search: ^0.4.8
  enum_to_string: ^1.0.14
  flutter_archive: ^2.0.1
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1
  flutter_downloader: ^1.5.2
  freezed_annotation: ^0.12.0
  get_it: ^5.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+15
  injectable: ^1.0.5
  intl: ^0.16.1
  json_annotation: ^3.1.1
  kt_dart: ^0.8.0
  moor: ^3.3.1
  moor_db_viewer: ^2.0.3
  multi_select_flutter: ^3.1.6
  rflutter_alert: ^1.1.0
  open_file: ^3.0.3
  path: ^1.7.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.18
  pdf: ^1.13.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  reactive_forms: ^7.6.2
  share: ^0.6.5+4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.3.0
  timeline_tile: ^1.0.0
  checkbox_formfield: ^0.1.0+3

  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_route_generator: ^0.6.10
  build_runner: ^1.10.9
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  freezed: ^0.12.6
  injectable_generator: ^1.0.6
  json_serializable: ^3.5.1
  lint: ^1.3.0
  moor_generator: ^3.3.1
```

But I don't understand why it works before and now it doesn't.

I have already tried looking for information on the web but did not find anything. I don't know what could have happened. Maybe it was the flutter update to version 2.0.2

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the latest version of [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route).

`ExtendedNavigator.builder` is deprecated now.
Use routeDelegate property of material app.

```
final _appRouter = AppRouter()
   ...
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return MaterialApp.router(
             routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(...initialConfig),
             routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
         ),
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I have a problem with my dependencies, because I am using json_serializable and it gives me an incompatibility error even though I update all versions of all packages And it seems that with the version I'm using of auto_route and auto_route_generator I can't have the _appRouter.delegate

Comment: Try updating json_serializable package also. https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable/install

Answer (score 1):

follow up on this thread, https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/378

temp solution is adding an onGenerateRoute or dummy widget to home property in materialapp widget

Comment: Yes, the comment about `home` property helped me: https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/378#issuecomment-796802877